# Laravel5 - Socialite meetup, how to return user()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite, meetup

I am getting the following error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1
ErrorException in Arr.php line 238:
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
in Arr.php line 238
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given', '/home/vagrant/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php', '238', array('array' => 'photo.photo_link', 'key' => array('birthday' => array('etc...
```

Redirecting is fine however upon return the problem begins.

As per the [socialite meetup documentation](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/meetup/) i am following the laravel way of handling authorisation however, failing to dump users details, what am i doing wrong?

my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Socialite;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AuthMeetupController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the meetup authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {

        if(\Input::has('code')){
            dd($this->handleProviderCallback());
        }
        return Socialite::driver('meetup')->redirect();


    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from meetup.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {

        $user = Socialite::driver('meetup')->user();

        dump($user);

        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have gotten round this by now but just in case, you might first want to check if the /support/Arr.php file is not messed up, check this https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Arr.php

Comment: Unfortunately i had to wait 3 months for a bug to be fixed in socialite, i will however have time again later this year to update, i'm sure it's been fixed i just cant get on that project.